# Pick a random integer $x\in[1,N]$ and guess the value of $N$

Tags: probability, puzzle

$N$ people arrive at a concert, with tickets numbered $1$ to $N$.

At the entrance, they all throw their tickets to a nearby trash can.

You pull out a ticket with some number $x$ written on it.

Based on that number, you need to guess how many people are at the concert.

What is be the best guess that you could come up with?

---

Apparently the answer is $x$, but I'm finding it hard to construct a probabilistic argument.

What I have in mind is that the number of people can be anything in the range $[x,\infty)$.

Then, the chances decrease as you go "further away" from $x$.

But I hardly consider this a good argument.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Using Bayes rule, you can pick $N$ where $1/N\cdot P(N)$ is maximum, but this depends on $P(N)$, don't you need to know that?

Comment: Obviously things dramatically change if you know in advance that the theatre cannot host more than, just to say, two thousand people.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I guess that those "colorful" details about the concert and everything are there just to make the puzzle "sound like a puzzle". In its pure mathematical form, I think that the question is summarized pretty well in the title.

Comment: It may help to know that this is a famous problem, the [German tank-counting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem), named because it was used to estimate the total number of German tanks based on the serials of encountered tanks during WWII.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Thank you for the historical enlightenment, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 0):

When you draw a ticket from the bin, you're drawing a Uniform(N) random variable.

The maximum likelihood estimate of $N$ given an observation $x$ is $\hat{N}=\arg \max_{N} (\text{Probability of observing x when the parameter is $N$})= \arg \max_{N} \begin{cases} 0 & x \leq N \\ \frac{1}{N} & x \geq N\end{cases}$, which is thus $\hat{N} = x$.

Aside: If you had multiple draws of a uniform distribution, the maximum likelihood parameter estimates are the largest and smallest tickets.